# Getting null data on response body using retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2, response

I am new to retrofit 2 and i am trying to get json array data but getting null, this is the url for getting the data.

But the funny thing is when i try to debug inside `onResponse` i am getting success message as well as `response.body` data. What is the problem here?

https://xenzet.com/GameCheat/viewgamesjson.php

this is json data

```
[
    {
        "gameid":"2",
        "gameIcon":"https:\/\/xenzet.com\/GameCheat\/uploads\/counter strike 1.6.png",
        "Games_Name":"1"
    },
    {
        "gameid":"3",
        "gameIcon":"https:\/\/xenzet.com\/GameCheat\/uploads\/gta.ico",
        "Games_Name":"vice city sucjlfsdrgefdsrhag"
    },
    {
        "gameid":"4",
        "gameIcon":"https:\/\/xenzet.com\/GameCheat\/uploads\/pubg.png",
        "Games_Name":"pubg"
    },
    {
    "gameid":"5",
    "gameIcon":"https:\/\/xenzet.com\/GameCheat\/uploads\/doom.png",
    "Games_Name":"Doom Enternal"
    },
    {
    "gameid":"6",
    "gameIcon":"https:\/\/xenzet.com\/GameCheat\/uploads\/for.png",
    "Games_Name":"Fornite"
    },
    {
    "gameid":"9",
    "gameIcon":"https:\/\/xenzet.com\/GameCheat\/uploads\/dota2.png",
    "Games_Name":"dota2"
    }
]
```

this is the method which is trying to get data

```
 public void fetch_information() {

        ApiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class);

        Call<List<Games>> call = ApiInterface.GetGames();


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Games>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Games>> call, Response<List<Games>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                    gameslist = response.body();
                    gamescounter = gameslist.size();
                    adapter = new GameRecyclerViewAdapter(GamesActivity.this, gameslist);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Games>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

this is ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static  String Base_URL ;

    public static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        if (retrofit == null)
        {
            Base_URL ="https://xenzet.com/GameCheat/";
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Base_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

and Api

```
public interface Api {

    @GET("viewgamesjson.php")
    Call<List<Games>> GetGames();
}
```

and in OnCreate i am calling fetch information method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_games);
    gameslist = new ArrayList<Games>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_gameslist);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
     fetch_information();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" +gamescounter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    adapter = new GameRecyclerViewAdapter(this, gameslist);

   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setClickListener((GameRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener) this);
}
```

trying to fill data of game list in recycler view but fails as it null.

this is logcat

```
2019-05-27 14:03:43.261 1261-1261/com.example.quizgames E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.quizgames, PID: 1261
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.quizgames.GamesActivity$1.onResponse(GamesActivity.java:109)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

This is class Games

```
public class Games {

    @SerializedName("gameid")
    @Expose
    private String gameid;
    @SerializedName("gameIcon")
    @Expose
    private String gameIcon;
    @SerializedName("Games_Name")
    @Expose
    private String gamesName;

    public String getGameid() {
        return gameid;
    }

    public void setGameid(String gameid) {
        this.gameid = gameid;
    }

    public String getGameIcon() {
        return gameIcon;
    }

    public void setGameIcon(String gameIcon) {
        this.gameIcon = gameIcon;
    }

    public String getGamesName() {
        return gamesName;
    }

    public void setGamesName(String gamesName) {
        this.gamesName = gamesName;
    }

//    public Games(String Gameid,String Gameicon,String GameName)
//    {
//      this.gameid = Gameid;
//      this.gameIcon = Gameicon;
//      this.gamesName = GameName;
//
//    }

}
```

This is recycler view

```
class GameRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Games> mGames;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    GameRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Games> games) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mGames = games;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gameitem, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }



    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Games Game = mGames.get(position);
        String Gameid = Game.getGameid();
        String Gameicon = Game.getGameIcon();
        String Gamename = Game.getGamesName();
        holder.GameNameTxt.setText(Gamename);
        Glide.with(holder.GameIconImage.getContext()).load(Game.getGameIcon()).thumbnail(0.1f).
                placeholder(R.color.colorPrimary).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(holder.GameIconImage);

    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {


        return mGames == null ? 0 : mGames.size();

    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView GameNameTxt;
        ImageView GameIconImage;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            GameNameTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gamename);
            GameIconImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }


    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    }
}
```

Comment: add Error from Logcat

Comment: not getting error in retrofit method ,the error is of recyclerview adapter as item count is null.

Comment: debug and check `response.body()` retrive data or not.

Comment: getting response body in debug only, trying without debugging gives null.

Comment: please check if you have added @SerializedName on data members of your Game.class, this annotation helps retrofit to parse json data to your java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add data in your Adapter in side onResponse Method

add `fetch_information()` in oncreate

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Games>> call, Response<List<Games>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                gameslist = response.body();
                adapter = new GameRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, gameslist); 
                //change your Activity name here insted of MainActivity
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
```

Comment: no change, i think it is not going inside OnRepsonse and OnFailure method , tried debugging does not go inside , only run to cursor in debug state i got inside the response method and it fills data there.

Comment: didnt work data still not found, the gamelist is empty.

Comment: add gameslist = new ArrayList<Games>();  above adapter initialization in oncreate

Comment: i did on top of class. still no improvement

Comment: You have the url @Nikunj Paradva why dont you try to get data and if you get results back you can post back the full thing you did , if you are able too.

Comment: issue is not for the responce, your List is not initialized as per your error  log in question, so initialize your arraylist in oncreate then after pass that in to adapter

Comment: does not work and after showing toast gives error recycleview set adapter on null object reference.

Comment: update fetch_information() method code, and what is on line number 109

Comment: did that no change , also added recyclerview class and which line 109 , not seeing line number here.

Comment: tell me which line was 109? I am compiled your code and  i got responce successfully  check it out https://gist.github.com/fakefacebook/48b96d0aad034f2349c9c6af3783dc8e

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you set up your list adapter in onCreate(), where `gameslist` is still null.

```
adapter = new GameRecyclerViewAdapter(this, gameslist);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When you call the setAdapter() method, the recyclerView will ask the adapter for the number of items; and in getItemCount() I suppose, you have something like return gameslist.count(). Since gameslist is still null, this causes the NPE.

To fix it, change getItemCount() to something like this:

```
return gameslist == null ? 0 : gameslist.size()
```

**EDIT**

I checked your URL (with Postman), and it appears that the content-type of the response is `text/html` and not `application/json` as it should be. I suppose that therefore the response isn't converted using Gson and thus you end up with null.

Comment: yes you are right it resolves error but the response data is still null why?

Comment: can any one try to get this data using the url in retrofit 2.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check where you make mistake. But this code implementation returning me list having 10 data inside list.

```
public interface APIInterface {

    @GET()
    Call<List<ViewGame>> viewgamesjson(@Url String url);

}
```

This is model class:

```
public class ViewGame {
    String gameid,gameIcon,Games_Name;

    public String getGameid() {
        return gameid;
    }

    public void setGameid(String gameid) {
        this.gameid = gameid;
    }

    public String getGameIcon() {
        return gameIcon;
    }

    public void setGameIcon(String gameIcon) {
        this.gameIcon = gameIcon;
    }

    public String getGames_Name() {
        return Games_Name;
    }

    public void setGames_Name(String games_Name) {
        Games_Name = games_Name;
    }
}
```

This is APiClient Class:

```
public class APIClient {
    static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static String Base_URL = "https://xenzet.com/GameCheat/";


    public static APIInterface getInterface() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Base_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
    }
}
```

And this is API Call:

```
 private void viewGame() {
        Call<List<ViewGame>> call = APIClient.getInterface().viewgamesjson("https://xenzet.com/GameCheat/viewgamesjson.php");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ViewGame>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ViewGame>> call, Response<List<ViewGame>> response) {
                try {
                    Global.dismissProgress();

                    if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        Global.dismissProgress();

                        Global.printLog("size===", response.body().size() + "");

                    } else {
                        Global.dismissProgress();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Global.dismissProgress();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ViewGame>> call, Throwable t) {
                Global.dismissProgress();
                try {
                    Global.showToast(SplashActivity.this, getString(R.string.something_wrong));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                call.cancel();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @tim long - there is issue might be   "@Expose" inside your Model Class. Remove it, and check it again.

Comment: none has worked for me and i have no clue what so ever, i think i am doing every thing fine

Comment: @timlong i provide everything to you. Its working fine. There may be some minor thing you are missing. You can delete your model and regenerate it again. This is also works.